# Object-oriented design riddle

Tags: c#, oop, object-oriented-analysis

Consider you have an `abstract base class` A that is inheriting from other class X.

Class A override Method `foo1`.

There are few other classes A1,A2,A3 which are `concrete` classes.

All concrete classes inherit method `foo1`.

Method `foo1` is almost like general algorithm that should be suitable for all concrete classes.
It is "almost" because of one exception in the algorithm there is an if condition, some of the classes lets say only A1,A3 need to luanch some other method `foo2` in the start of `foo`.

For A2 we don't need to launch `foo2`.

The problem is if I that if I implement `foo2` in class A all it's children will inherit this function as well, which is not so good design?

I thought of excluding `foo2` to an Interface which will be  implemented by concrete classes-> but this is not good as `foo1` which calls `foo2` is on the base class!

Any ideas how to solve this problem in a proper way?

Thank you

Comment: You could make foo2 private in A, and instead add a protected virtual property which sub classes can overwrite, and which is used by A to determine if the sub class wants to call foo2 in the beginning of foo1.

Comment: I think I understand and see a solution, but I think it'd be better if you added some simplistic code to your question ala `abstract class MyShape {....`.  I'm not sure I follow, but that would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I would use in that situation is make another layer of abstract classes that the classes that need the special `Foo2` derive from instead.

```
abstract class A : X
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        //Foo logic
    }
}

abstract class B : A
{
    protected virtual void Foo2()
    {
        //Foo2
    }

    override void Foo()
    {
        Foo2();
        base.Foo();
    }
}

public A1 : B
{
}

public A2 : A
{
}

public A3 : B
{
}
```

Comment: The only downside of this implementation is that it adds another base class with a distinction that is probably not obvious from the class name.

Comment: @lukegravitt In the real world I would expect more decriptive names like `X = Shape`, `A = Polygon`, `B = Quadralateral`, `A1 = Parallelogram`, `A2 = Triangle`, and  `A3 = Trapezoid`

Answer (score 2):

You could have some kind of internal Foo1 Initializer that you can override in the child class.

```
public abstract class A {
    internal virtual void Foo1Init() {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo1Init");
    }

    public void Foo1() {
        Foo1Init();
        Console.WriteLine("Foo1");
    }
}

public class A1 : A {
    internal override void Foo1Init() {
        Console.WriteLine("A1 Foo1Init Override");
    }
}

public class A2 : A {

}

public class A3 : A {
    internal override void Foo1Init() {
        Console.WriteLine("A3 Foo1Init Override");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a1 = new A1();
        a1.Foo1();

        var a2 = new A2();
        a2.Foo1();

        var a3 = new A3();
        a3.Foo1();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A1 Foo1Init Override  
Foo1  
Foo1Init
Foo1
A3 Foo1Init Override  
Foo1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in your base class that the subclasses can set when they need to have foo2() called:

```
public class BaseClass {
    protected bool RunFoo2 { get; set; }

    public BaseClass() {
        // Not really needed, since booleans default to false
        RunFoo2 = false;
    }

    public virtual void foo1() {
        if (RunFoo2)
            foo2();
        // Default code here
    }

    public virtual void foo2() {
        // Whatever
    }
}

public class A : BaseClass {
    public A() : base() {
        RunFoo2 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make foo2() private, non-virtual or both in this case as well, depending on the specific needs.